# MediaPlayer.setDataSource() throwing IOException following new release to the Play Store

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have an app that plays sounds from a user's device. These sounds are assigned to different pads, so that the user can select which sounds correspond to which pads and come back and play these at the touch of a button. Everything works as expected, until I issue an updated release to production, then for some reason, setDataSource() starts throwing an IOException (setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000) for users who already have sounds loaded and permissions granted. I managed to replicate this at one point on my own device, and if the same sound is then loaded to a different pad, all of a sudden, the original one will start working again, so it must be to do with permissions. My code is as follows. The first few methods are how I initially get the URIs and take permissions. playButtonIndexSound() is the method that is throwing exceptions. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

```
private void requestReadExternalStoragePermission() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 11);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 11 && grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        findNewMedia();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission to access this device's external storage has been denied.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private void findNewMedia() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestReadExternalStoragePermission();
    } else {
        permissionGrantedGetNewMedia();
    }
}

private void permissionGrantedGetNewMedia() {
        try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        // Persist the permission, even on phone restart
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.setType("audio/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_REQUEST_CODE);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "This device has not provided a way to access it's external storage. You are unable to load sounds.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);
        }
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);
    currentUri = null;
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == OPEN_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultData != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: resultData.getData(): " + resultData.getData());
                currentUri = resultData.getData();
                assert currentUri != null;
                // Persist the permission, even on phone restart
                int takeFlags = resultData.getFlags();
                takeFlags &= (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                ContentResolver resolver = this.getContentResolver();
                resolver.takePersistableUriPermission(currentUri, takeFlags);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void playButtonIndexSound(final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int btnNumber) {

   // currentSoundObject is a global variable set in another method
   currentUri = Uri.parse(currentSoundObject.getUri());

   if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error resetting MediaPlayer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, currentUri);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error setting data source MediaPlayer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (loopSounds) {
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error setting loop function", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            try {
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error preparing MediaPlayer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error resetting MediaPlayer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                try {
                    mp.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error starting MediaPlayer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);` Better remove as that makes no sense. You cannot grant anything there. You should be glad that in onActivittyResult() you are granted access.
  `

Comment: From what I've read on SO, this is how others are persisting permissions. It solved the problem of losing permissions on phone-restart, but hasn't solved the problem of losing permissions when upgrading the app.

Comment: `resolver.takePersistableUriPermission(currentUri, takeFlags);` That is the way to tale persistable uri permissions indeed.

Comment: Losing permissions when upgrading an app should not happen. This no normal behaviour. Any specific device in use?

Comment: It's happening on various devices and Android versions. I've been reading this morning and wondering if it may have something to do with Proguard obfuscating or removing code? There's no problem during testing, only when updating in the Play Store, so it would make sense that Proguard might cause problems.